# How to replace 'n\' from a string (not \n) in Php

Tags: php

I have a string which contains `n\` by mistake (as imported from csv). So,I just want to replace `n\` with `\n`.

**Possible conditions :** `n\,\n\n, n\\n,n\n\`

```
   $string = "hello\n how n\n\ are you?\n\nis everything\nn\ok buddy, n\ where have you been. \n";
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It will remove all the possible matches as per your question:-

```
$str = "main_string_goes_here";
$replace = "n\,\n\n,n\n\,\nn\,n\\n";
$arr = explode(",",$replace);
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    str_replace($value,"\n",$str);
}
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Are you getting the expected output or facing some problem??

Comment: i got the expected output after a little update in $replace. Thanks - please up vote the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
str_replace("n\","\n",$string);
```

Here we search for the string, find the value "n\" and then replace the value with "\n". Update this example with your conditions.

Comment: try doing it you cant use `"n\"` php won't allow you to do. syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

Comment: the slash should be escaped. try `"n\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$string = 'hello\n how n\n\ are you?\n\nis everything\nn\ok buddy, n\ where have you been. \n';
$string = str_replace('n\\n\\','&new*',$string);
$string = str_replace('\\n\\n','&old*',$string);
$string = str_replace('n\\','\\n',$string);
$string = str_replace('&new*','\\n\\n',$string);
echo $string = str_replace('&old*','\\n\\n',$string);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/904353

As other says to replace `"n\"` to `"\n"` will not work. You need to escape `\` backslash also

Comment: hello\n how \n\n are you?`\\nnis` everything\n\nok buddy, \n where have you been. \n . This is the output look closely `\\nnis`

Comment: @AafaqAhmad : this the exact output you want

Comment: @AafaqAhmad : your question was not simple as other was thinking, it was needed other trick like I did now.

Comment: yes it is not simple as others are thinking it to be .Output i got now is `hello\n how n\n\ are you?\n\nis everything\n\nok buddy, \n where have you been. \n`  string still contains n\

Comment: Expected output: `hello\n how \n\n are you?\n\nis everything\n\nok buddy, \n where have you been. \n`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php
echo $string = 'hello\n how n\n\ are you?\n\nis everything\nn\ok buddy, n\ where have you been. \n';


$new_str = preg_replace('~[\\\\/:*?"<>|]~', ' ', $string);
echo $text = str_replace('n', '', $new_str);

?>
```

Comment: no proper output.  
hello\n how \n\n are you?`\\nn`is everything\n\nok buddy, \n where have you been. \n

Comment: Please try its : 
$new_str = preg_replace('~[\\\\/:*?"<>|]~', ' ', $string);
echo $text = str_replace('n', '', $new_str);

Comment: look closely the last word `been`. [https://eval.in/904376](https://eval.in/904376)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
 $string = 'hello\n how n\n\ are you?\n\nis everything\nn\ok buddy, n\ where have you been. \n';

 echo str_replace('n\\', '\n',$string );
```

Comment: have you checked the output . [https://eval.in/904332](https://eval.in/904332). Output still has n\

Comment: yes. there was issue with previous code. I updated same. you can check it now.